# Science Fiction movie from the 80's or 90's about aliens that crash land on earth and are helped by a young girl

Tags: story-identification, movie

Its been a long time since I saw this movie, but here are the details I remember.

A family of humanoid aliens and their "protector" crash on Earth. They are being chased by an assassin. They communicate telepathically. A young girl living near the crash site helps the alien family and falls in "love" with one of the aliens. There is a chase scene through the woods. That's all I can remember!

Comment: If not for the assassin, I'd think it was "Earth Girls are Easy" from 1988. ;-P

Answer (score 10):

Could this be [*Stranded*](http://www.moviefone.com/movie/stranded/1033818/synopsis) [1987]:

> Any film with a cast that runs the age-and-experience gamut from Ione Skye to Maureen O'Sullivan is certainly worth at least one look. Stranded casts Ione as a lonely 17-year-old, living in a remote farmhouse with her grandmother, O'Sullivan. Late one evening, five space aliens crash-land near the farm. Holding Skye and O'Sullivan prisoner, the extraterrestrials run afoul of the law when one of them impulsively kills Ione's boyfriend, who happens to be the son of local hothead and rabblerouser Michael Greene. Despite the aliens' laser weaponry, sheriff Joe Morton intends to treat the incident as a standard hostage crisis, but Greene wants to storm the farmhouse, with no consideration of Skye and O'Sullivan's safety. In true "Stockholm syndrome" fashion, the hostages befriend the more likeable aliens--one of whom is played by Flea, bass player for the Red Hot Chili Peppers. A curious blend of several genres, Stranded has true cult-classic potential, should any distributor want to give it a second chance on the midnight-movie circuit.

Comment: IMDB says just about nothing about this movie, and Wikipedia doesn't know it exists!

Comment: Thank you!!! Stranded is the movie I was looking for!!!

Comment: @Ryan-Blocker - check the checkmark beside my answer (and possibly click the up-arrow as well if you approved of the answer).